# HTML5 web audio - long recordings being truncated

Tags: javascript, html, audio, recording

Does anyone have any thoughts as to why a recording would get truncated when using HTML5 audio?  It only seems to happen when the recordings are around a minute and a half.  The audio usually gets truncated around 30 seconds (or less).  Shorter recordings do not get truncated.

We're using Matt Diamond's recorder.js functionality. There can be more than one HTML5 player dynamically created on a page (up to 5), but the number of players don't seem to be part of the issue as the truncation happens when there's only 2 players on the page.

The buffer length is 4096.  The audio is saved out to file on disk as a wav file.  The user can hear the full audio recording when they play it back through the HTML5 player if they're still on the same page, but the file that is saved out is truncated.

Any ideas on why this happens or how to overcome it would be greatly appreciated!

I forgot to mention this is in an asp.net web application.  We use Sox in the code behind to normalize the audio file prior to saving it to disk.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: It will take me some time to create a small example as our asp.net web app is fairly complex, and I have other issues I'm working on to resolve.  I'll try to get one up as soon as possible.  I'm updating my question with a bit more background info in case that helps.

Comment: I've created a basic web app. It's set up with two audio controls. I tested recording the same passages that get cut off in our actual web app. The audio played back correctly in the audio control and in the wav file saved to disk. I'm going to try normalizing the files w/ SOX when saving the blobs as wav files on disk.

Comment: I've added jsnlogging to our web app, and after recording for around 3 minutes discovered the log file contained an "uncaught exception: out of memory".  Any suggestions on the best way to handle long recordings?